# Show that the normal equations are identical to $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}QS(\theta)=0~\forall~j=1,\ldots,k$

Tags: statistics, summation, proof-verification

> > Let the quadratic sum be given by $QS(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-x^i\theta)^2$, with $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)^T, \theta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_k)^T$ and
> >     $$
> > X=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & \ldots & x_{1k}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ x_{n1} & \ldots & x_{nk}\end{pmatrix}.
> > $$
> >     Show that the normal equations $X^TX\theta=X^Ty$ are identical with
> >     $$
> > \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j} QS(\theta)=0~\forall~j=1,\ldots,k.
> > $$

Hi, good evening, here is my proof.

The normal equation is $\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X}\theta=\textbf{X}^Ty$. It is
\begin{equation}
\textbf{X}\theta=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & \ldots & x_{1k}\\x_{21} & \ldots & x_{2k}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\x_{n1} & \ldots & x_{nk}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\theta_1\\ \vdots\\ \theta_k\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{1i}\theta_i\\\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{2i}\theta_i\\ \vdots\\ \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{ni}\theta_i\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and from this for the left hand side (LHS) it follows
\begin{equation}
LHS=\textbf{X}^T\textbf{X}\theta=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{21} & \ldots & x_{n1}\\x_{12} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{n2}\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ x_{1k} & x_{2k} & \ldots & x_{nk}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{1i}\theta_i\\\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{2i}\theta_i\\ \vdots\\ \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{ni}\theta_i\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{i1}x{ij}\theta_j\\\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{i2} x_{ij}\theta_j\\\vdots\\\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{ik}x_{ij}\theta_j\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
For the right hand side (RHS) it is
\begin{equation}
RHS=\textbf{X}^Ty=\begin{pmatrix}x_{11} & x_{21} & \ldots & x_{n1}\\x_{12} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{n2}\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ x_{1k} & x_{2k} & \ldots & x_{nk}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i1}y_i\\\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i2}y_i\\\vdots\\\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ik}y_i\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
So the normal equations are given as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{is}x_{ij}\theta_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{is}y_i, s=1,\ldots,k.~~(+)
\end{equation}

It is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}QS(\theta)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-x^i\theta)^2\right), x^i\theta=\sum_{s=1}^{k}x_{is}\theta_s.
\end{equation}
With the chainrule for partial differentiation and binomial rule it is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-x^i\theta)^2\right)&=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(y_i^2)}_{=0}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(y_i x^i\theta)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}((x^i\theta)^2)\\
&=-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_{ij}+2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{s=1}^{k}x_{is}x_{ij}\theta_s
\end{align}
Now assume that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}QS(\theta)=0$ for all $j=1,\ldots,k$ then it is
\begin{equation}
-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_{ij}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{s=1}^{k}x_{is}x_{ij}\theta_s
\end{equation}
resp. after division by $-2$ on both sides
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{s=1}^{k}x_{is}x_{ij}\theta_s~\forall 1\leqslant j\leqslant k.
\end{equation}
So this equations are the same then the equations (+). So it does not matter if we say that the normal equations have to be fullfilled or if we want that the partial derivatives of the square sum all have to be $0$.

---

Is my proof okay? I know its lot of calculation but maybe somebody is motivated to say me if my proof is correct.

With kind regards

math12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks fine. Or you can simply use matrix algebra. Since 
$$
QS(\theta)=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\theta)^\prime (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\theta)
$$
it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}QS(\theta)=\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}^\prime(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\theta)+(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\theta)'\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}=0\\
=\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}'\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{y}'\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}-\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot j}\mathbf{X}\theta-\theta\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}=0
$$
Note that all terms are scalars, meaning that the transposed terms are equal to the non-transposed ($\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}$ is column $j$ of $\mathbf{X}$).
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}QS(\theta)
=2\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}'\mathbf{y}-2\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot j}\mathbf{X}\theta=0\\
\Rightarrow\mathbf{x}_{\cdot j}'\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot j}\mathbf{X}\theta=0
$$
So then by stacking these partial derivatives (skipping the constant $2$):
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}QS(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}QS(\theta) \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_2}QS(\theta) \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_K}QS(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}_{\cdot 1}'\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot 1}\mathbf{X}\theta \\ \mathbf{x}_{\cdot 2}'\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot 2}\mathbf{X}\theta \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_{\cdot K}'\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}'_{\cdot K}\mathbf{X}\theta\end{pmatrix}=\boldsymbol{0}.
$$
This is equal to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1'\mathbf{y} \\ \mathbf{x}_2'\mathbf{y} \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_K'\mathbf{y}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}'_1\mathbf{X}\theta \\ \mathbf{x}'_2\mathbf{X}\theta \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}'_K\mathbf{X}\theta\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}_1'\\ \mathbf{x}_2'\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_K'\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{y}  = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}'_1 \\ \mathbf{x}'_2 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}'_K\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}\theta\\
$$
and since $\mathbf{X}=(\mathbf{x}_{\cdot 1}, \mathbf{x}_{\cdot 2}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{\cdot K})$ it follows that this is
$$
\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X}\theta,
$$
i.e. the normal equations.

Comment: Thank you. Glad to hear that my efforts are okay. And of course thank you for the alternative proof. Looks less elementar but more nice.^^